# How to load items from combox into datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

How can I get items from combobox in to datagridview and when i click on a cell in datagridview it will lead me to edit so i'm thinking for edit when user clicks on a cell i will display its raw item in texbox and when user press enter it will change in in datagridview as well as in combox
how should i do this in vb.net

Comment: SO is not a place to answer "how can I" questions, you need to present your code, and from there we can help diagnose problems.

Comment: If both controls use the same datasource, this will be done automatically. But without seeing any attempt, it's hard to give you complete advice. Maybe research `DataSource` and `DataBindings` to see if that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be more clear with your question.

But, for example if you have some items in your ComboBox you can copy them to DGV like this:

```
For Each item In ComboBox.Items 'loops over combobox
    DataGridView.Rows.Add(item) 'adds a new row to datagridview and puts a value from combobox in it
Next
```